# @forProviders not working in scala view

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.6, play-authenticate

Any methods from @import com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html._ (Play! authenticate library) isn't working! See the log:

> Uncaught error from thread [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16]: com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html.forProviders_Scope0$forProviders.*display*(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable;, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode]
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html.forProviders_Scope0$forProviders.*display*(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/reflect/Manifest;)Lplay/twirl/api/Appendable;

The cause is `NoSuchMethodError`, but i can't figure out how to import this `@forProviders` method in my scala view. The import from sample is not working!

Scala view:

```
@(playAuth: com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate, skipCurrent: Boolean = true)

@import com.feth.play.module.pa.views.html._

<ul class="providers">
    @forProviders(playAuth, skipCurrent) { p =>
        <li>
        @if(p.getKey() == "openid") {
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="askOpenID('@p.getUrl()');">
        } else {
            <a href="@p.getUrl()">Icon</a>
        }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

PS.: I'm following the sample play-authenticate-usage (the basic auth) from joscha github